# sqlite query on path as directory, ogr2ogr

Tags: sqlite, ogr2ogr

I am using ogr2ogr to remove null geometries rows in a shapefile. All works fine when work in the directory and run the command below without the path. To do this efficiently, I need to be able to query on the shapefile by giving its path. The sqlite part of my query is

select * from d:/data/fema/toload/CA/ImperialCounty/06025C_20160805/S_BASE_IN
DEX where geometry is not null

I get the error Unrecognized token: ":", which I think is just part of sqlite expecting a table name instead of my path.

The question is: how do you query a table with sqlite using the table's absolute path?

Comment: An SQLite file is a database, so it has a file name, and can contain multiple table names.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify the absolute path in the SQL query, just specify it for the shapefile.

```
ogr2ogr -sql "SELECT * FROM S_BASE_INDEX" "D:\RESULTS\OutputFile.SHP"
    "D:\data\fema\toload\CA\ImperialCounty\06025C_20160805\YourShapeFile.shp"
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. I've included the line below that did the job. This is roughly doubling the size of the dbf files. I haven't looked yet at exactly what is happening. Are perhaps types being changed, say from int to some long floats? I would expect everything to be preserved exactly.                                                   `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" -dialect sqlite -sql "select * from S_FIRM_PAN where geometry is not null" d:\data\fema\tolo
ad\CA\ImperialCounty\06025C_20160805\S_FIRM_PANnonempty.shp d:\data\fema\toload\CA\ImperialCounty\06025C_20160805\S_FIRM
_PAN.shp`